# Google Analytics V3 ASP.Net API beta 1.5 OAuth2 error

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using the latest beta 1.5 (1.5.0.28991) of Google APIs with a service account, and am hitting this error on the AssertionFlowClient line when doing auth:

> Method not found: 'Void DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientBase..ctor(DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServerDescription, System.String, System.String)'.

DotNetOpenAuth V4.3.1.13153

```
AuthorizationServerDescription desc = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description;
X509Certificate2 key = new X509Certificate2(key_file, key_pass, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
AssertionFlowClient client = new AssertionFlowClient(desc, key) { ServiceAccountId = client_id, Scope = scope };
```

I'm breaking my head over this - any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the exact problem. Do you have add NuGet references to Google.Apis and Google.Apis.Authentication? Can you try to compile our Plus sample (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Plus.ServiceAccount/Program.cs?repo=samples)? It uses service account as well. Let me know if it works, if so - try to continue and change the code to adapt the analytics API.

Comment: Thank you, peleyal. I was missing Google.Apis.Authentication, your suggestion and the asnwer below helped me sort it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the sample from...

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Plus.ServiceAccount/Program.cs?repo=samples

(The download link has a bad certificate, so you can't use Chrome to download it, you have to use IE)

Steal the packages.config and app.config files from the "Plus.ServiceAccount" project and place them in your project.

Reload your project, then on the "Package Manager Console" when it asks to download the packages, let it.

That made the error go away for me.  I must have been using the wrong version of...something.

Comment: Perfect - thank you! Missed Google.Apis.Authentication in packages.config

Answer (score 0):

I was checking out the analytics API yesterday and noticed how undocumented it is and no samples etc.

Any ways, I have created a library that you could use to access analytics easily with couple of lines and make direct databinding to DataTables for data returned it's open source on the github so feel free to contribute :)

https://github.com/rmostafa/DotNetAnalyticsAPI

Usage

```
Analytics.AnalyticsManager manager = new Analytics.AnalyticsManager(Server.MapPath("~/bin/privatekey.p12"), "YOUR_EMAIL");
            manager.LoadAnalyticsProfiles();

List<Analytics.Data.DataItem> metrics = new List<Analytics.Data.DataItem>();
metrics.Add(Analytics.Data.Session.Metrics.visits);
List<Analytics.Data.DataItem> dimensions = new List<Analytics.Data.DataItem>();
dimensions.Add(Analytics.Data.GeoNetwork.Dimensions.country);


System.Data.DataTable table = manager.GetGaDataTable(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3), DateTime.Today, metrics, dimensions, null, metrics);
```

There is direct code mapping for All Google API Reporting commands categorized same way like the API so you could it even without reading the API Documentation at all since all features there are documented in the attributes, I have wrote code that parsed the complete api documentation and resourced the Metrics, Dimensions, Calculated Features in an XML that i generated from physical classes that you could use directly like the example above it's fun to play with :) enjoy